# ContentProvider update() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, insert-update

Something's probably wrong with the implementation of `update()` method but I'm not sure what is:

```
 @Override
 public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
 }
```

Here's how I call the method:

```
Random r1 = new Random();
long insertValue1 = r1.nextInt(5);
updatedValues.put(Provider.adPoints, insertValue1);
int value = getContentResolver().update(Provider.CONTENT_URI, updatedValues, null, null); //insert(Provider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I also want to make use of `count` and return the number of row updated in `update()`. What seems to be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no update code in Switch . I think you missed it

Comment: By update code, do you mean `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange()`?

Comment: something like database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, condition , selectionArgs).. there is only break is present

Comment: refer this link to know more about content providers https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/

Comment: Turns out, `update()` method never runs inside my implementation of ContentProvider. When I call `getContentResolver().update`, it calls the `update()` method in `ContentResolver` directly. However, I do call `insert()` method directly as well, but the `insert()` method does pass by my implementation of `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the rows updates with a Content Provider then you have to do this:

First make sure that you have a reference of your DatabaseHelper class in the ContentProvider:

```
private YourDatabaseSQLLiteHelper mDbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDbHelper = new YourDatabaseSQLLiteHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}
```

Then override the update() method on your content provider:

```
@Override
public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues cv, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
    int rowsUpdated;

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {

        case YOUR_TABLE_CODE:

            // This is what you need.
            rowsUpdated = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(
                    YourTableContract.YourTableEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    cv,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;

        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }

    if (rowsUpdated != 0)
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

Then when you call the method, it must return how many rows were updated.

```
int rowsUpdatedCount = getContentResolver().update(...);
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier, but mine's a non-db ContentProvider. I user a custom Item class where I set the values and add them to ContentProvider via ArrayList, like `ArrayList<Item>`. But I pretty much understood what you meant by the code. This should work!